# Describe function in Hmisc and prettyR - masking problems

Tags: r, package, masking

I like aspects of the **prettyR** `describe` function and aspects of **Hmisc** `describe` function. When both packages are loaded, the **prettyR** `describe` masks the **Hmisc** `describe`. I have looked around and found that code such as:

```
Hmisc::describe(flu$nprloc3)
```

will supposedly make the Hmisc describe take precedence. I've tried this but I seem to still get the prettyR output. Am I doing anything wrong? I've also tried to find a way to just unload the prettyR package from my global environment (but not uninstall it) but have not been successful.

Comment: Can you provide an example and proof that `Hmisc::describe` is not being called in the case you quote? To unload a loaded package try `detach(package:prettyR, unload = TRUE, force = TRUE)` (the `force` bit may or may not be required.)

Comment: I tested it and the behavior (to my surprise as well) was as described.

Comment: Thanks Gavin - will try this as well to keep my global environment lean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hmisc::describe` is generic and may need to be called by the particular class-extension.

```
 methods(describe)
#[1] describe.data.frame describe.default    describe.formula    describe.matrix    
#[5] describe.vector
```

Try:

```
Hmisc::describe.vector(1:10)
```

(I'm not sure this is supposed to be what is happening and it still may be a problem with how one or both of these packages are constructed. I'd nominate prettyR as the likely offender here, since prettyR::describe is not generic, and it seems to be crippling the generic dispatch in keeping Hmisc::describe from working properly)